# Efficiently syncing large Perforce repository?

Tags: perforce

I have troubles getting the latest version from the perforce server . The depot is very large and I don't want to do a complete checkout as it would tale a long time . Instead I put the unversioned sources and dependencies in the workspace and do a "p4 sync -k" . This successfully versions my files but it doesn't bring the new files from the server .

How can I do that ?

Comment: You are going to have to provide more information.  There are a total of 630 other questions on Perforce.  This means that out millions of questions, only 630 people, have asked a question about Perforce.  You are going to have to provide more information.  When you say the depot is large, how large are we talking about, my guess the entire problem is the fact your using the unversioned source.

Comment: try just `p4 sync`? the -k option is not supposed to pull files from the server. `p4 help sync` is your friend.

Comment: @Ramhound . The depot is large enough to take more than 10 hours to obtain the complete sources and dependencies. The unversioned files where obtained from the perforce server by someone else and I want to use them instead of having to check averything out again.

Comment: @IanGilham  . The problem is that "p4 sync" takes forever on it's own . That why I first try "p4 sync -k" and only then "p4 sync" ,but the message I get is "File(s) up-to-date" which they are, but there are a lot of files on the server, which on the client are missing.

Comment: If "p4 sync" takes forever on its own, either your client view is too large (i.e., you are trying to sync waaaay much more than you need) or it could be that an old version of the server is being used. Every server version seems to have performance improvements, so for a very large repo you (i.e., the site's administrators) should make sure to keep the server updated.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed as off-topic. Syncing a large repository is a definitely related to software development and the (better) answer provided by p4-randall is valuable information. Perhaps changing the question title to say 'Efficiently syncing large Perforce repository?' instead of 'Perforce Update'.

Comment: I agree, this question should not have been closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your situation:

- You work against a very large project.
- You have a local snapshot of the data that is not entirely up to date.
- You wish to only obtain the differences between your snapshot and the latest on the server.

The steps you should follow are:

- Run `p4 sync -k` to make Perforce think you have the latest copy of all files.
- Run `p4 diff -se ... | p4 -x - sync -f` to force-sync any out of date files
- Run `p4 diff -sd ... | p4 -x - sync -f` to force-sync any missing files

At that point you may have local files that were deleted from the server.  If you care about those, you can write a simple script that detects them and removes them from your file system.

The good news is that Perforce's next release (2012.1) has a `status` command that will pick up all differences more easily.

To approach this from another angle, do you need the entire project in your workspace?  Could you narrow your workspace view to only work with a subset of the data?

Comment: Excellent news about the `status` command. Can you give an example of it's usage?

Comment: See [this link](http://www.perforce.com/blog/120126/new-20121-p4reconcile-p4status) for examples of 'p4 status'

Comment: p4 blog linked by user1054341 moved; link is now http://www.perforce.com/blog/120206/new-20121-p4-status-and-p4-reconcile

Comment: And moved there: https://www.perforce.com/blog/new-20121-p4-status-and-p4-reconcile

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic Perforce question.

To achieve this you will need pipe a few commands together.

`p4 diff -sd //Depot/Path/... | p4 -x – sync -f`

1. `p4 diff -sd` command will find all the files that do not exist in the workspace.
2. `p4 -x – sync -f` will forcible sync these files.

As p4-randall has in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9179521/73025), you may also want to run `p4 diff -se ... | p4 -x - sync -f` to sync any files that are out-of-date.

HTH,